# How to correctly express an intention to work on a certain day instead of working on another day?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, expressions, phrase-requests

How to say "I will work on Saturday instead of working on Tuesday" in a more natural fashion?

I guess the verb will be constructed like "work or make" + "out or off or ?", but what is the exact construction?

Comment: Maybe something with words "switch to a different work shift"? (I'm not a native speaker)

Comment: I will work Saturday instead of Tuesday?

Comment: Your example sounds entirely natural to me, though it could be shortened like in WS2's version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No particular pair of daynames occurs often enough in OP's context for me to back this up with usage counts from Google Books, but in my experience native speakers are more likely to say...

> *"I'll **do** Saturday instead of Tuesday"*.

Having said that, there's nothing at all wrong with ***work*** (or ***come in***, etc., in some contexts).